# Проблема двойного запроса curl

Tags: php, php-curl

Проблема заключючается в следущем:
Я захотел написать для своего сервера плагин для уведомления донатеров и себя о заходе и выходе с сервера, для этого я использовал VK API работающий через http запросы. И написал следующие:

```
<?php
namespace src;
use pocketmine\plugin\Plugin;
use pocketmine\plugin\PluginBase;
use pocketmine\event\Listener;
use pocketmine\event\player\PlayerLoginEvent;
use pocketmine\event\player\PlayerQuitEvent;
use pocketmine\Player;
use pocketmine\Server;
class main extends PluginBase implements Listener{
    public function onEnable(){ $this->getServer()->getPluginManager()->registerEvents($this, $this); }
    public function onlog(PlayerLoginEvent $e){
        $p  = $e->getPlayer();
        $model = str_replace(' ', '+', $p->getDeviceModel());
    $ch = curl_init("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?chat_id=3&random_id=0&message=⟩+Игрок+{$p->getName()}+вошёл+на+сервер!%0AУстройство:+{$model}&access_token=скрыт&v=5.131");
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return true;
    }
    public function onQuit(PlayerQuitEvent $e){
        $p1 = $e->getPlayer();
        $model1 = str_replace(' ', '+', $p1->getDeviceModel());
        $ch1 = curl_init("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?chat_id=3&random_id=0&message=⟩+Игрок+{$p1->getName()}+вышел+с+сервера!%0AУстройство:+{$model1}&access_token=скрыт&v=5.131");
        curl_exec($ch1);
        curl_close($ch1);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Во время проверки curl почему-то отправил 2 ЗАПРОСА за раз!
И в итоге в вк было следуещее:
[image: вот собственно и оно.]

Comment: это не курл отправил два за раз, а метод onQuit вызвали два раза

Comment: А используете как? Не смущает что функции onlog и onQuit то же самое делают, не отсюда ли дубли?

Comment: @InDevX там разные сообщения.

Comment: зы: есть такие штуки как `http_build_query` и `url_encode` если что.

Comment: @teran таки  да, одно слово разное) где-то dry всплакнул в сторонке

Comment: @InDevX, может мне просто нужно сделать пустой инит и юрл просто как opt поставить?

Comment: @BsoDin890 Попробуйте, если очень хочется. Но это ничего не изменит. Где-то срабатывает дважды функция, тут вряд ли в curl дело

Comment: @BsoDin890 Сначала попробуйте в консоль сервера залогировать триггеры этих событий. Я давно работал с Minecraft PE. Если память не изменяет, то это делается так: `$this->getLogger()->info("здесь ваш текст");`. Если в логах видите по два сообщения, значит обработчик срабатывает дважды и нужно разбираться с ним. Если по одному сообщению, значит что-то с http-запросом

Comment: Нет, я просто на гкодил чёрт возьми. Я сделал пустой курл инит, а юрл поставил как option. И всё работает

Comment: Это может быть проблема чего угодно

Comment: У меня две папки, с разнными серверами, один для проекта, второй для тестов. На с серве для тестов всё ок, а на проекте нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это была проблема с namespace
Основной класс находился так:

+->vkbot/
|
+-->src/
|
+--->src/
|
+---->main.php
|
+-->plugin.yml

---plugin.yml---

```
name: vkbot
api: 3.0.0
main: src\main
version: 1.0.0
```

Спасибо @xRef за небольшую заметку к дебагингу.